# CDK Stepfunction Fargate step that takes all json key

Tags: aws-cdk

I wanted to create ECS task that takes all json as its environment input. But my cdk code won't deploy because of following error message, the error message is so vague and it is difficult for me to figure out why my code is wrong.

```
Failed to call Step Functions for request: 'com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.CreateStateMachineRequest'. (Service: null; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
        new StateMachine (/local/home/miae/Explanation/src/ForecastingDeepLearningExplanationInfrastructure/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions/lib/state-machine.ts:101:26)
```

My cdk code

```
...
const ecsFargateTask = new sfn.Task(this, 'myEcs', {
            inputPath: "$",
            resultPath: "$.ecs",
            task: new class implements sfn.IStepFunctionsTask {
                bind(): sfn.StepFunctionsTaskConfig {
                    return {
                        resourceArn: "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
                        parameters: {
                            "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                            "Cluster": props.cluster.clusterArn,
                            "TaskDefinition": taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn,
                            "Overrides": {
                                "ContainerOverrides": [{
                                    "Name": "myContainer",
                                    "Environment.$": "$.envs"
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    }
const chain = sfn.Chain.start(ecsFargateTask);
new sfn.StateMachine(this, `StateMachineCopy${props.stage}`, {
            definition: chain,
            timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(3000)
});
```

This is the Step function I want, and I could manually create this without problem.

```
{
    "StartAt": "ExplanationEcs",
    "States": {
        "ExplanationEcs": {
            "End": true,
            "InputPath": "$",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789:cluster/myCluster482E02CC-1VWQ5XRG4II88",
                "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789:task-definition/myTaskDefinitionE3E6548C:3",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "myContainer",
                            "Environment.$": "$.envs"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "ResultPath": "$.ecs"
        }
    },
    "TimeoutSeconds": 3000
}
```